# tree negative pattern not working with watch

Tags: bash

I want to `watch` the `tree` structure of a directory.

If I call `tree -L 2 -I '*vfp*'` all is well and I see no directories

```
.

0 directories, 0 files
```

...but if I try and `watch tree -L 2 -I '*vfp*'` I see everything without the effect of `-I`

```
Every 2,0s: tree -L 2 -I *vfp*                                                                                                                   

vfp-directory
├── ckpts
├── data
│   ├──  100.wav
│   ├──  101.wav
│   ├──  102.wav
...
```

What am I missing here? How can I `watch` the directory and see the same as what I see with a bare call to `tree`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do :

```
watch tree -L 2 -I '*vfp*'
```

What `watch` sees is :

```
tree -L 2 -I *vfp*
```

So you need to do

```
watch tree -L 2 -I "'*vfp*'"
```

The reason why `watch` sees differently has to do with how `bash` parses command line.

When `bash` parses this line :

```
watch tree -L 2 -I '*vfp*'
```

it removes quotes around the arguments, so it runs `watch` command with 5 arguments : [tree], [-L], [2], [-I], [*vfp*].

Comment: Great answer. Could you clarify _why_ the stated output is what is apparent to `watch` in your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to escape your single quotes:

`watch tree -L 2 -I \'*vfp*\'`